# Loading data from Database with Atk4

Tags: php, model-view-controller, atk4

To be hones working with Atk4 is a great adventure for such a rookie as I am. and now i have really a problem i can't solve by myself.
I have two tables in MySQL database. The first one is named user (id, username, email) and the second one is named trips (id, user_id, name). I have made a login and register form for users. I want a logged user to be able to see it's own trips. I used to make this thing for its profile information using the following code:

```
<?php
class page_userprofile extends Page{
    function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->api->auth->check();
    $model = $this->add('Model_user');
    $this->add('FormAndSave')->setModel($model)->loadData($this->api->auth->get('id'));

}
}
```

I have to do something similar with Model_trips but I do not know what. i have tried with 
that example from Atk4 website:

```
// Traverse foreign keys. Automatically loads proper model and data
$company=$emp->getRef('company_id');
```

This is the last code I have written:

```
<?php
class page_mytrips extends Page{
    function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->api->auth->check();
    $model = $this->add('Model_trips');
    $this->add('FormAndSave')->setModel($model)->loadData($this->getRef('user_id'));

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close:

```
$model = $this->add('Model_trips');
$model->setMasterField('user_id', $this->api->auth->get('id'));
```

Afterwards you can use model inside CRUD, MVCGrid, MVCForm or MVCLister, the following rule will apply:

- When listing, only trips belonging to current user will be shown
- When adding, user_id will be set to current user's id

Sometimes I add function:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
    function getTrips(){
         return $this->add('Model_trips')
              ->setMasterField('user_id',$this->get('id'));
    }
}
```

Then you can make use the following.

```
$model = $this->add('Model_user')->loadData($user_id)->$getTrips();
```

Handy if you want to see other users trips.